# SQL Server backup status Report with PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell, report, database-backups

I got a PowerShell script for reporting SQL backup status on multiple servers, it works fine but it had no function to send mail. I added that part and now I am able to get the mail with the attachment.

The only concern is, I want the report to show "NA" and not a default date where the satabase is in Simple Recovery Model or if backup has not happened. Can someone please advise?

Here is the code, just in case someone needs it unlike my requirement:

```bsh
$ServerList = Get-Content "Serverlist location"
$OutputFile = "to save the report location"

$titleDate = Get-Date -UFormat "%m-%d-%Y - %A"
$HTML = '<style type="text/css">
    #Header{font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;}
    #Header td, #Header th {font-size:14px;border:1px solid #98bf21;padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;}
    #Header th {font-size:14px;text-align:left;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:#A7C942;color:#fff;}
    #Header tr.alt td {color:#000;background-color:#EAF2D3;}
    </Style>'

$HTML += "<HTML><BODY><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100% id=Header>
        <TR>
            <TH><B>Database Name</B></TH>
            <TH><B>RecoveryModel</B></TD>
            <TH><B>Last Full Backup Date</B></TH>
            <TH><B>Last Differential Backup Date</B></TH>
            <TH><B>Last Log Backup Date</B></TH>
        </TR>"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null
foreach ($ServerName in $ServerList)
{
    $HTML += "<TR bgColor='#ccff66'><TD colspan=5 align=center><B>$ServerName</B></TD></TR>"

    $SQLServer = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $ServerName
    foreach ($Database in $SQLServer.Databases)
    {
        $HTML += "<TR>
                    <TD>$($Database.Name)</TD>
                    <TD>$($Database.RecoveryModel)</TD>
                    <TD>$($Database.LastBackupDate)</TD>
                    <TD>$($Database.LastDifferentialBackupDate)</TD>
                    <TD>$($Database.LastLogBackupDate)</TD>
                </TR>"
    }
}

$HTML += "</Table></BODY></HTML>"
$HTML | Out-File $OutputFile

$emailFrom = "send email address"
$emailTo = "recipient email address"
$subject = "Xyz Report"
$body = "your words "
$smtpServer = "Smptp server"
$filePath = "location of the file you want to attach"

function sendEmail([string]$emailFrom, [string]$emailTo, [string]$subject,[string]$body,[string]$smtpServer,[string]$filePath)
{
    $email = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $email.From = $emailFrom
    $email.To.Add($emailTo)
    $email.Subject = $subject
    $email.Body = $body
    $emailAttach = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment $filePath
    $email.Attachments.Add($emailAttach)
    $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
    $smtp.Send($email)
}

sendEmail $emailFrom $emailTo $subject $body $smtpServer $filePath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<TD>$($Database.LastBackupDate)</TD>
```

with something like

```
<TD>$(if ($Database.RecoveryModel -eq 'Simple' -or $Database.LastBackupDate -eq '01/01/0001 00:00:00') {'NA'} else {$Database.LastBackupDate})</TD>
```

Do the same for `LastDifferentialBackupDate` and `LastLogBackupDate`.

---

With that said, I strongly recommend looking into [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx), [`ConvertTo-Html`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730936.aspx), and [`Send-MailMessage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx), which would allow you to greatly simplify your code:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null

$emailFrom  = 'sender@example.com'
$emailTo    = 'recipient@example.com'
$subject    = 'Xyz Report'
$smtpServer = 'mail.example.com'

$style = @'
<style type="text/css">
...
</style>
'@

$msg = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\serverlist.txt' |
       ForEach-Object {New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' $_} |
       Select-Object -Expand Databases |
       Select-Object Name, RecoveryModel,
           @{n='LastBackupDate';e={if ($_.RecoveryModel -eq 'Simple' -or $_.LastBackupDate -eq '01/01/0001 00:00:00') {'NA'} else {$_.LastBackupDate}}},
           @{n='LastDifferentialBackupDate';e={if ($_.RecoveryModel -eq 'Simple' -or $_.LastDifferentialBackupDate -eq '01/01/0001 00:00:00') {'NA'} else {$_.LastDifferentialBackupDate}}},
           @{n='LastLogBackupDate';e={if ($_.RecoveryModel -eq 'Simple' -or $_.LastLogBackupDate -eq '01/01/0001 00:00:00') {'NA'} else {$_.LastLogBackupDate}}} |
       ConvertTo-Html -Head $style | Out-String

Send-MailMessage -From $emailFrom -To $emailTo -Subject $subject -Body $msg -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $smtpServer
```

[See also](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/05/02/use-powershell-to-report-sql-server-backup-status/).

Comment: Can't edit my previous message, press entered before i was done.
Anyhow, i was able to get the desired result with your help like this:-

<TD>$(if($Database.LastBackupDate -eq '01/01/0001 00:00:00') {'NA'} else {$Database.LastBackupDate})</TD> 

Your simple code compared to mine was a huge help. Will check on the links. I tried running your edited code and i get the following error:

Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified
 method is not supported.

Comment: The parameter `-Body` expects a string, but `ConvertTo-Html` produces a list of strings, so its output must be merged into a single string. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, appreciate your guidance.

Comment: I know this thread is old but if you are still around have one query, i ended up modifying this report further where i wanted only those backup details which was more than 4hrs and with color codes, it works perfectly but in the HTML report the server name gets written for those that does not meet the criteria, i tried putting some "if" condition before the part where it writes the server Nmae but cant seem to make it work. I have updated the script in this post. Thanks

Comment: If you have a followup question: please post a new question. Do not move the target.

Comment: Sorry, i thought it will be a repeated question. Thanks will do.